# Query two databases with the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, multiple-databases

I need to run the same query on two different databases.

I edited my previous db class obtaining this

```
class Db {

function connect() {
    $db = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Error");
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $db);
    return $db;
}

function connect2() {
    $db = mysql_connect(DB_HOST2, DB_USER2, DB_PASSWORD2) or die("Error 2");
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME2, $db);
    return $db;
}

function sql_query($sql) {

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connect()) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql, $this->connect2()) or die(mysql_error());   



}  }
```

Is there a way to avoid the connection to the databases each time? I already tried using $GLOBALS to save the database links but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you really have two different database host/user/password combinations, or are these identical? If they are the same, then querying two databases with a single connection is possible: `SELECT * FROM db1.table2 as a,db2.table2 as b;`. Again, only possible if `DB_HOST` = `DB_HOST2` and `DB_USER` = `DB_USER2`.

Comment: Thanks but I have two different databases on different servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP PDO manual

http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php

Using PDO you can make two connections at the same time then you can run two queries on two different databases too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mysql_pconnect()` which will establish a persistent connection to your MySQL database.  You could then save the link for future reference.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php for more details.